# Return Types in Java (Critique Too Please)

Tags: java, function, loops, methods, syntax

Given my program below, I am a little confused about what the return line actually does in a method. No matter what variable I put there, it still returns the same values when I call the method in my main class. What exactly does using the return (variable name) do in any method that is not a void? Are you supposed to list a return statement for each variable in your method header? Sorry I'm just trying to really understand methods. Also, can you please critique my overall program. Does it make sense? Does it seem well written? Thank you!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int seconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, days=0;

        System.out.println("We will convert seconds to minutes hours and days!");
        System.out.println("How many conversions would you like to do?");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int conversion =keyboard.nextInt();
        for (int count = 1; count <= conversion; count++)
        {
                Calculator.convert();
        }
    }
    public static void convert()
        {
            System.out.println("Enter seconds: ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            double seconds, minutes, hours, days;
            seconds = keyboard.nextInt();
            minutes = seconds/60.0;
            hours = minutes/60.0;
            days = hours/24.0;
            System.out.println("Minutes: " + minutes + " Hours: " + hours + " Days: " + days);


        }


}
```

Comment: Brush up some basics!! You need to first think of the purpose of your function. Based on the purpose you need to decide what input (parameters of the function) it will accept and what output (return value) it will produce. All the Best.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a return in your method because you don't use it. Returns are used to return a value to the program that called a function. For exemple, if you want to have back the "days" value, you should call the method like this :

```
double days = Calculator.convert(seconds, minutes, hours, days);
```

But if you don't need to become back in your program a value generated by the method, your method should return nothing. Nothing is specified with the keyword "void". For example :

```
public static void convert(double seconds, double minutes, double hours, double days)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter seconds: ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            seconds = keyboard.nextInt();
            minutes = seconds/60.0;
            hours = minutes/60.0;
            days = hours/24.0;
            System.out.println("Minutes: " + minutes + " Hours: " + hours + " Days: " + days);
        }
```

Comment: Since user input is obtained within the method, there's no need for the method _arguments_ either.  Even if you prompted the user in the main method, you'd only want to pass `seconds`, since all the other values are derived.

Comment: I just tweaked my code with the suggestions made. Is it better now?